# System::Configuration - Can't create/save user.config in AppData/Local

Tags: .net, visual-c++, app-config, system.configuration, user.config

I have been searching high and low for the proper way to use System::Configuration to create and modify a user.config file located under AppData/Local/myapplicationname/.  I use the configuration manager to open a local user level configuration object.  The user.config file does not exist yet under AppData/Local, so I call the Configuration::Save() method to create it (MSDN documentation states that this method will create the file if it does not exist).

```
Configuration^ C = ConfigurationManager::OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel::PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
MessageBox::Show(C->FilePath); // Shows "rootpath/AppData/Local/myappname/user.config"
MessageBox::Show(C->HasFile.ToString()); // Shows "false" since user.config hasn't been created yet.
C->Save(ConfigurationSaveMode::Full);
```

And nothing happens, the user.config file is not created and there are no error messages.  If I use Configuration::SaveAs() instead, I get the error message:

```
"The file name 'rootpath\AppData\Local\myappname\user.config' is invalid because the same file name is already referenced by the configuration hierarchy you have opened."
```

What am I doing wrong here?  I'm very annoyed with MSDN's lack of explanation on how to use System::Configuration for anything besides app.config.  I do not want to use app.config since the settings are user-level and can be changed at any time by the user.  I would use app.config if I had to, but can't even do that because of UAC.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks all!